# Array(with Keys) or JSON to String in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to format Arrays to a string because I want to write it into my log-file. The Format should be:

```
key=value; key1=value1; ...
```

It should also work with Arrays with Keys or JSON objects.

Comment: I would consider either `serialize()` or `json` both are pretty bullet proof, but do not generate the format you say you need. How important is that exact format. Using serialize or json, you wont have to worry about the first time you come across a complex array with sub arrays and sub sub arrays and maybe an object or 2 thrown in. It is all done for you with a simple function call. JSON Strings are much more humanly readable than serialize output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function arrayToString($array){
    $result="";
    while($object = current($array)){
        $result .= key($array) . "=";
        if(is_array($object)) {
            $result .= arrayToString($object);
        } else {
            $result .= $object;
        }
        $result .= "; ";
        next($array);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

There you go

Answer (score 0):

You can use http_build_query() for that:

```
$data = array("k1" => "v1","k2" => "v2","k3" => "v4");
$string = http_build_query($data,"", "; ", PHP_QUERY_RFC1738);
```

modify the `"; "` if you want a different seperator.
The `PHP_QUERY_RFC1738` to have `+` as spaces. This should be the default, but you comments sounds like you might use `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986`.

If you don't want that replace it:

```
$string = str_replace("+"," ", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but it encoded it to an URL format so @ -> %40 or something like this